# Unable to edit the label text

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have tried to insert the data into the ToDo List and it is working but i am unable to edit the name and number field in the edit box of ToDo list.

And also the list is showing is not properly having padding and i tried to put padding in the list but whole list is shifting towards the left.

Also I tried with table concept in JavaScript but for that i need the loop and the database but i dont want to use the database or any other storage

```js
var taskInput = document.getElementById("new-task");
var nameInput = document.getElementById("new-name");
var numberInput = document.getElementById("new-number");
var addButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var incompleteTask = document.getElementById("incomplete-tasks");
var completedTask = document.getElementById("completed-tasks");


var createNewTaskElement = function (taskString, nameString, numberString) {

    var listItem = document.createElement("li");

    var checkBox = document.createElement("input");

    var label = document.createElement("label");
    var label1 = document.createElement("label1");
    var label2 = document.createElement("label2");

    var editInput = document.createElement("input");
    var editInput1 = document.createElement("input");
    var editInput2 = document.createElement("input");

    var editButton = document.createElement("button");
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

    label.innerText = taskString;
    label1.innerText = nameString;
    label2.innerText = numberString;

    checkBox.type = "checkbox";
    editInput.type = "text";
    editInput1.type = "text";
    editInput2.type = "text";

    editButton.innerText = "Edit";
    editButton.className = "edit";
    deleteButton.innerText = "Delete";
    deleteButton.className = "delete";

    listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
    listItem.appendChild(label);
    listItem.appendChild(editInput);
    listItem.appendChild(label1);
    listItem.appendChild(editInput1);
    listItem.appendChild(label2);
    listItem.appendChild(editInput2);
    listItem.appendChild(editButton);
    listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
    alert("You added '" + label.innerText + "' to the ToDO list");
    return listItem;
}

var addTask = function () {
    var listItem = createNewTaskElement(taskInput.value,nameInput.value,numberInput.value);
    if (taskInput.value == "") {
        alert("You must enter a task");
    } 
    else if (nameInput.value == "") {
        alert("You must enter a Name");
    }
    else if (numberInput.value == "") {
        alert("You must enter a Phone Number");
    } else {
        incompleteTask.appendChild(listItem);
        
    }
    bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);

    taskInput.value = "";
    nameInput.value = "";
    numberInput.value = "";
}

var editTask = function () {

    var listItem = this.parentNode;

    var editInput = listItem.querySelector('input[type=text]');
    var label = listItem.querySelector("label");
    var containsClass = listItem.classList.contains("editMode");

    if (containsClass) {
        label.innerText = editInput.value;
        alert("You edited " + label.innerText);
    } else {
        editInput.value = label.innerText;
    }
    listItem.classList.toggle("editMode");
}

var deleteTask = function () {
    var listItem = this.parentNode;
    var ul = listItem.parentNode;
    alert("You deleted " + listItem.querySelector("label").innerText);
    ul.removeChild(listItem);
}

var taskCompleted = function () {
    var listItem = this.parentNode;
    completedTask.appendChild(listItem);
    bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskIncomplete);
    alert("You completed " + listItem.querySelector("label").innerText);
}

var taskIncomplete = function () {
    var listItem = this.parentNode;
    incompleteTask.appendChild(listItem);
    bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);
}

var bindTaskEvents = function (taskListItem, checkBoxEventHandler) {
    var checkBox = taskListItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
    var editButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.edit");
    var deleteButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.delete");

    editButton.onclick = editTask;

    deleteButton.onclick = deleteTask;

    checkBox.onchange = checkBoxEventHandler;
}

for (var i = 0; i < incompleteTask.children.length; i++) {
    bindTaskEvents(incompleteTask.children[i], taskCompleted);
}

for (var i = 0; i < completedTask.children.length; i++) {
    bindTaskEvents(completedTask.children[i], taskIncomplete);
}

var input = document.getElementById("new-number");

input.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        addTask();
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
    height: 525px;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li * {
    float: left;
}

li,
h3 {
    clear: both;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input,button {
    outline: none;
}

button {
    background: none;
    border: 0px;
    color: #888;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    color: #333;
}

h3, label[for='new-task'] {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
    padding: 30px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

input[type="text"] {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    color: #888;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    color: #333;
}

label[for='new-task'] {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}

input#new-task,#new-name,#new-number {
    width: 260px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input:focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
    border-color: #5AB0DB;
}

input:hover {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

p>button:hover {
    color: #0FC57C;
}

li {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

li>input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
}

li>label {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 190px;
    padding: 0 0 0 11px;
}

li>input[type="text"] {
    width: 180px;
}

#completed-tasks label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #888;
}

ul li input[type=text] {
    display: none;
}

ul li.editMode input[type=text] {
    display: block;
}

ul li.editMode label {
    display: none;
}

th{
    padding-right: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>To DO List</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #ebeff0">
    <div class="container">

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Add Task</h3>
        <br>
        <label>Add Task</label>
        <input id="new-task" type="text" required><br>

        <label>Name</label>
        <input id="new-name" type="text" required><br>

        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input id="new-number" type="text" required><br>

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Todo</h3>
        
        <ul id="incomplete-tasks">
            
        </ul>

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Completed Tasks</h3>
        <ul id="completed-tasks">
            
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the class and then edited the inputs

```js
var taskInput = document.getElementById("new-task");
var nameInput = document.getElementById("new-name");
var numberInput = document.getElementById("new-number");
var addButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var incompleteTask = document.getElementById("incomplete-tasks");
var completedTask = document.getElementById("completed-tasks");


var createNewTaskElement = function (taskString, nameString, numberString) {

    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var checkBox = document.createElement("input");

    var label = document.createElement("label");
    var label1 = document.createElement("label");
    var label2 = document.createElement("label");

    var editInput = document.createElement("input");
    var editInput1 = document.createElement("input");
    var editInput2 = document.createElement("input");

    var editButton = document.createElement("button");
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

    label.innerText = taskString;
    label1.innerText = nameString;
    label2.innerText = numberString;

    label.className = "task";
    label1.className = "name";
    label2.className = "number";

    checkBox.type = "checkbox";
    editInput.type = "text";
    editInput1.type = "text";
    editInput2.type = "text";

    editInput.className = "edit";
    editInput1.className = "edit1";
    editInput2.className = "edit2";

    editButton.innerText = "Edit";
    editButton.className = "edit";
    deleteButton.innerText = "Delete";
    deleteButton.className = "delete";

    listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
    listItem.appendChild(label);
    listItem.appendChild(editInput);
    listItem.appendChild(label1);
    listItem.appendChild(editInput1);
    listItem.appendChild(label2);

    listItem.appendChild(editInput2);
    listItem.appendChild(editButton);
    listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
    alert("You added '" + label.innerText + "' to the ToDO list");
    return listItem;
}

var addTask = function () {
    var listItem = createNewTaskElement(taskInput.value, nameInput.value, numberInput.value);
    if (taskInput.value == "") {
        alert("You must enter a task");
    } else if (nameInput.value == "") {
        alert("You must enter a Name");
    } else if (numberInput.value == "") {
        alert("You must enter a Phone Number");
    } else {
        incompleteTask.appendChild(listItem);

    }
    bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);

    taskInput.value = "";
    nameInput.value = "";
    numberInput.value = "";
}

var editTask = function () {

    var listItem = this.parentNode;

    var editInput = listItem.querySelector('.edit');
    var editInput1 = listItem.querySelector('.edit1');
    var editInput2 = listItem.querySelector('.edit2');

    var label = listItem.querySelector(".task");
    var label1 = listItem.querySelector(".name");
    var label2 = listItem.querySelector(".number");

    var containsClass = listItem.classList.contains("editMode");

    if (containsClass) {
        label.innerText = editInput.value;
        label1.innerText = editInput1.value;
        label2.innerText = editInput2.value;
        alert("You edited " + label.innerText);
    } else {
        editInput.value = label.innerText;
        editInput1.value = label1.innerText;
        editInput2.value = label2.innerText;
    }
    listItem.classList.toggle("editMode");
}

var deleteTask = function () {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this task?") == true) {
        var listItem = this.parentNode;
        var ul = listItem.parentNode;
        alert("You deleted " + listItem.querySelector("label").innerText);
    } else {
        alert("You cancelled the task");
    }

    ul.removeChild(listItem);
}

var taskCompleted = function () {
    var listItem = this.parentNode;
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to mark this task as complete?") == true) {
        completedTask.appendChild(listItem);
        bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskIncomplete);
        alert("You completed " + listItem.querySelector("label").innerText);
    } else {
        alert("You cancelled the task");
    }
}

var taskIncomplete = function () {
    var listItem = this.parentNode;
    incompleteTask.appendChild(listItem);
    bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);
}

var bindTaskEvents = function (taskListItem, checkBoxEventHandler) {
    var checkBox = taskListItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
    var editButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.edit");
    var deleteButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.delete");

    editButton.onclick = editTask;

    deleteButton.onclick = deleteTask;

    checkBox.onchange = checkBoxEventHandler;
}

for (var i = 0; i < incompleteTask.children.length; i++) {
    bindTaskEvents(incompleteTask.children[i], taskCompleted);
}

for (var i = 0; i < completedTask.children.length; i++) {
    bindTaskEvents(completedTask.children[i], taskIncomplete);
}

var input = document.getElementById("new-number");
```

```css
.container {
    height: 525px;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li * {
    float: left;
}

li,
h3 {
    clear: both;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input,button {
    outline: none;
}

button {
    background: none;
    border: 0px;
    color: #888;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    color: #333;
}

h3, label[for='new-task'] {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
    padding: 30px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

input[type="text"] {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    color: #888;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    color: #333;
}

label[for='new-task'] {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}

input#new-task,#new-name,#new-number {
    width: 260px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input:focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
    border-color: #5AB0DB;
}

input:hover {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

p>button:hover {
    color: #0FC57C;
}

li {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

li>input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
}

li>label {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 0 0 11px;
}

li>input[type="text"] {
    width: 100px;
}

li>button{
    padding-left: 3px;
}
li>button:hover{
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: #c54f0f;
}

#completed-tasks label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #888;
}

ul li input[type=text] {
    display: none;
}

ul li.editMode input[type=text] {
    display: block;
}

ul li.editMode label {
    display: none;
}

#AddBtn{
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black !important;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>To DO List</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #ebeff0">
    <div class="container">

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Add Task</h3>
        <br>
        <label>Add Task</label>
        <input id="new-task" type="text" required><br>

        <label style="padding-right: 05px;">Name</label>
        <input id="new-name" type="text" required><br>

        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input id="new-number" type="text" required><br>
        <button id="AddBtn" onclick="addTask()">Add</button>

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Todo</h3>
        
        <ul id="incomplete-tasks">
            
        </ul>

        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Completed Tasks</h3>
        <ul id="completed-tasks">
            
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```